# Where is zero width space in Microsoft Word for Mac?

Tags: macos, microsoft-office

I'm using Microsoft Word for Mac 2011 on OS X El Capitan.

How do I use a zero width non-joiner character? AKA a no-width/zero-width space?

I've attempted to find it in the "Insert" > "Symbol" > "Symbol Browser..." in Word, and via the OS X Keyboard > Emoji and Symbols dialog.

These can be used for breaking really long URLs or paths at the end of a line so the entire path is not pushed to a new line leaving a gap on the line above.

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis 
nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

Essentially this
is_my_problem.com/it/is/really/annoying/to/read/a/document/and/come/across
/this
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The zero width space and zero width non-joiner are available in the OS X Emoji & Symbols dialog, or you can copy it from a webpage that employs the HTML code.

**tl;dr**  To insert the symbol, place your cursor in the correct place in the document, open the Emoji & Symbol dialog, find the zero width space, and double click on it.

### Finding the Emoji & Symbol Dialog

In OS X El Capitan, the keyboard shortcut to open the dialog is <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd>. Older versions of OS X [apparently used](http://blog.isaach.com/2013/03/zero-width-space.html) <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>.

Note: the keyboard shortcut does not work in Word. Instead, you need to show the button in the menu bar and click it open.

[image: OS X Keyboard preferences]

[image: OS X keyboard menu button]

### Finding the Zero Width Space or Non-Joiner Character

Search for "space" and choose the zero width space option.

[image]

Or search for "joiner" and choose the zero width non-joiner option.

[image]

### Option 2: Copy it

Go to [this codepen](https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/iLKwm) and copy the symbol then paste it where you want it.

Comment: It should be noted that `ZERO WIDTH SPACE` and `ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER` are different characters.

Answer (score 2):

In Word (on Windows) you can insert Unicode characters by typing the code-point value and pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>.

The Unicode codepoint value for `ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER` is `U+200C`, so you would do the following:

**Find where you want the ZWNJ:**
[image]

**Enter and select the Unicode code-point value:**
[image]

**Press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>:**
[image]

This can be done with arbitrary Unicode characters, so it's quite a useful trick.

---

**Edit:**
Using the <kbd>Option</kbd> key in place of <kbd>Alt</kbd> apparently doesn't work. However, on Mac you should be able to accomplish this by holding down the <kbd>Option</kbd> key, pressing the keys that correspond to the digits of the code-point, and then releasing <kbd>Option</kbd>.

If that doesn't work, you might be able to use the "More Symbols..." dialog, but I've had mixed results using this. You can enter a code-point into the box in the window:
[image]

This will move the selector in the window to the code-point value you enter. By "mixed results," I mean that it won't work if the code-point isn't in the window.

Comment: This is a useful answer and I upvoted. I was really optimistic and just tried it, but it resulted in this character: ≈

Comment: I tried doing this with `&#8204;` instead of `200C` and got the same ≈ character.

Comment: @Joseph: Thanks for letting me know. I've edited my answer to include what should be another way of doing this.

Comment: I tried the new way (holding option). If I hold it and type 200c I get ™ººç and if I hold it and type 8204 I get •™º¢. Any other permutations, such as the full `&#8204;` result in similar non-sense. I think OS X just has a broken user experience for these kinds of characters.

Comment: @Joseph: The only option left I know of would be the one in my new addition to my answer. However, this only works if the symbols box displays the code-point you're looking for. Otherwise, you'll need to use another source for the character (such as copying it from somewhere).